# Typesafe heterogeneous containers involving generics

Tags: java, generics, types, effective-java

I need to create a container that provides a way for me to store elements of generic type, kind of like [this effective java pattern](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2861454&seqNum=8) but storing generic things

Is it possible to create a typesafe heterogeneous container where generic typed things are involved?

```
<T> void put(T ele, SomeTypedThing<T> genEle);
<T> SomeTypedThing<T> get(T ele);
```

I am fine to add the `Class<T>` as method param. example:

```
public static class Container {

    Map<Class<?>, Set<?>> store = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void put(Set<T> ele, Class<T> type) {
        store.put(type, ele);
    }

    public <T> Set<T> get(Class<T> type) {
        return store.get(type);
    }
}
```

would it be possible to achieve this?

```
Set<?> raw = store.get(type);
Set<T> typed = // some magic;
```

how, or why not? is it something that java doesn't do or is it something fundamental (so no language can do, or just doesn't make sense to do)

Comment: You are going to have an unsafe cast _somewhere_.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the wildcard parameter on the `Set`. Instead of using a `Set<?>`, make it a `Set<Object>`, and everything works:

```
public static class Container {

    Map<Class<?>, Set<Object>> store = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void put(T ele, Class<T> type) {
        store.putIfAbsent(type, new HashSet<>());
        store.get(type).add(ele);
    }

}
```

The difference between `Set<?>` and `Set<Object>` is this:

A `Set<?>` could be a `Set` of any type - it could be a `Set<String>` or a `Set<Integer>`. And the java compiler wants to make sure that you are not trying to add a `String` object to a `Set<Integer>`.

On the other hand, a `Set<Object>` is just a `Set` that can contain instances of the `Object` class. And since `String` and `Integer` are both subclasses of `Object`, you can easily store strings and Integers into such a set.

Adding the method

```
    public <T> Set<T> get(Class<T> type) {
        return (Set<T>) store.get(type);
    }
```

to the class gives a compiler warning about an unchecked cast. This warning can be safely ignored here, because you know that you added only elements of type `T` to that `Set`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. You're right, I totally missed that, however, what I am really trying to solve is the second part of the question. I will edit the post to say the same.

Comment: @aoak added the `get` method to the answer

Comment: I agree with the solution but I was wondering if something without an unchecked cast is possible. All I want is to say that the key and value are typed on same type in `Map<T, Something<T>>`. Is imposing such constraint possible? If not, why not? (Theoretically)

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this problem a few weeks ago as I needed a typesafe heterogenous container (THC) for literally any object (including generic interface implementations) AND any number of them (like two keys that provide a String for example).

Although this question is rather old, I'd like to provide another approach.

THCs are all about parameterizing the keys. So you can use a key object that wraps the class type instead of using the class type as key.

For example:
Key-Class:

```
static class Type<T> {
    private final Class<T> object_type;

    public Type(String name, Class<T> object_type){
        this.object_type = object_type;
    }
    public Class<T> getObjectType() {
        return object_type;
    }
}
```

Container-Class:

```
static class Container{

    private final Map<Type<?>, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> T get(Type<T> type){
        return type.getObjectType().cast(properties.get(type)); //no compiler complaints
    }

    public <T> void put(Type<T> type, T value){
        properties.put(type, type.getObjectType().cast(value)); //no compielr complaints
    }
}
```

Since we can't provide `Set<Foo>.class` as object type we have like two possibilites to deal with the generic type. Either we use inheritence or we use composition.

Inheritence:

```
static class IntHashSet extends HashSet<Integer>{}
```

Composition:

```
static class IntSetComposition{

    private final Set<Integer> set;
    public IntSetComposition(Set<Integer> set){
        this.set=set;
    }
    public Set<Integer> getSet(){
        return this.set;
    }
}
```

How to use all this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Type<String> string_type = new Type<>("string_type_1", String.class);

    Type<Integer> int_type = new Type<>("int_type_1", Integer.class);

    Type<IntHashSet> int_set = new Type<>("int_hashset", IntHashSet.class);        
    Type<IntSetComposition> int_set_comp = new Type<>("int_set_comp", IntSetComposition.class);        

    Container container = new Container();

    String s = container.get(string_type); //no compiler complaints
    int i = container.get(int_type); //no compiler complaints

    IntHashSet set = container.get(int_set); //no compiler complaints
    Set<Integer> set2 = container.get(int_set_comp).getSet(); //no compiler complaints

    String s2 = container.get(int_type); //the compiler does not like this!
}
```

Note: NotNull checks should be implemented as well as hashcode() and equals() overrides

Comment: very neat idea about that composition! I loved it

Answer (score 0):

Thomas Klägers solution is an answer that also came to my head. Creating an fully functioning heterogeneous container which works like this:

```
Set<?> raw = store.get(type);
Set<T> typed = // some magic;
```

But as far as I know, It is not possible to use container You mentioned with that 'smooth' code I quoted above. However it is usable and You can get sets of Your stored by class sets. Here goes the code:

```
public class Container {

    Map<Class<?>, Set<Object>> container = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void put(T e, Class<?> type) {
        container.putIfAbsent(type, new HashSet<>());
        container.get(type).add(e);
    }

    public <T> Set<T> get(Class<T> type) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //It is fine to ignore warnings here
        Set<T> res = (Set<T>) container.get(type);
        return res;
    }
}
```

And working example of storing ang retreiving Containers elements:
public class Run {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Bar bar = new Bar();

    Container con = new Container();
    con.put(foo, foo.getClass());
    con.put(bar, bar.getClass());

    Set<? extends Foo> foos = con.get(foo.getClass());
    Set<? extends Bar> bars = con.get(bar.getClass());

    //here You can use Your sets as ususal
}
```

If approach `<? extends Foo>` and usage is fine for You, it's working solution. Above that if You work in Java 10+, there's possibility for that 'dirty' declaration omission. Just declare it as `var` and poof, its hidden.