# Java downcasting using class literal

Tags: java, casting

So basically I have List with some container, that contain generic object:

```java
List<MyObj<?>> myObjList;
```

For example there can be `MyObj<A>` and `MyObj<B>`. And there some overloaded method `todo(A a)` and `todo(B b).`
If i wanna call this method in cycle, I need hardcode casting to `A` or `B`:

```java
for(MyObj<?> myObj: myObjList) {
    todo( (A) myObj.body() )
}
```

Is there a way to casting using class literal `A.class`?

I'm tried add class literal field to `myObj`:

```java
class myObj<T> {
    Class<T> classLiteral;
    T body;
}
```

and use `.cast()` method:

```java
for(MyObj<?> myObj: myObjList) {
    todo( 
         myObj.getClassLiteral().cast( myObj.body() )
    )
}
```

But it didn't work

Comment: and how would it work if you would pass list of `C` with such autocast?

Comment: "But it didn't work" - Compiler error, runtime exception? Please describe the output of your attempted approach.

Comment: You can capture wildcards with helper functions (see e.g. [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30763895/why-use-a-wild-card-capture-helper-method)). Also, within the methods of your `myObj<T>`, you can use the type `T`.

Comment: This question about [typesafe heterogeneous containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58967845/typesafe-heterogeneous-containers-involving-generics) might also provide some inspiration.

Comment: Sorry for missing.
Compiler says: "no suitable method found for todo(capture#1 of ?)".
I checked your links and learned a lot of new things. Thanks!
I'm tried add some foohelper(), but got same error.
`A` and `B` doesn't extends from each other and i can't change that since `A`, `B` and method `todo()` from external library.
So seems like there no way for autocast.