# Best way to construct an object class with a collection array of three elements

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I was thinking about making in Java a collection class of an array with three elements: object , string, boolean like in the way I can use in a loop like:

```
for ( objectArray collectionElement  : ArrayElementsCollection ) {
   if ( collectionElement.String == 'type_of_element' && collectionElement.boolean ) {
      // doing what I need with collectionElement.Object
   }
}
```

What would be the best way to implement it? Using an ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList>>? A map?

**EDIT Aug 15, 2023**

Thanks to @tgdavies , I figured simplest way to manage my list which was a collection of active interfaces based on @tgdavies sample, I made:

```
class myConnections {
    public String connectionName;
    public int connectionType;
    public Boolean connectionState;
    public String connectionAddress;

    .....
}

public class MainCustomClass() {
    
    private customConnections(){ collectionConnections = new ArrayList<myConnections>(); }
        
    public void getActiveConnections() {
        customConnections.clear();

        if (!localIPs.isEmpty() && localIPs.size() > 0) {
            IntStream.range(0, localIPs.size())
                .forEach(i -> customConnections.add(new myConnections(localHostnames.get(i), connectionType, connectionState, localIPs.get(i))));
        }
    }
}
```

so it worked for my scopes.  Thanks again @tgdavies!

Comment: You'll need to give a lot more detail about how you want to use this class. Please write some code showing the operations you'd perform on it.

Comment: Please illustrate what you are asking with some code.  So that we can understand what you mean by *"an array with three elements: object , string, boolean"*, for example.

Comment: There is no such thing as an array with three elements of different types.Your problem doesn't appear to require anything beyond `class A { Object o;String s; boolean b; ... }` and no array at all.

Comment: @user207421 - Well .... I was thinking that the OP *might* means an `Object[]` that *contained* instances of `Object`, `String` and `Integer`.  But either way, we shouldn't have to guess what the OP means.

Comment: Looks like you need a [Typesafe heterogeneous containers involving generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58967845/typesafe-heterogeneous-containers-involving-generics) - in your case maybe without the "generics" part, but in general this is like a "variant" type in other languages.

Comment: Please learn what Java naming conventions are, and use them.

Comment: @StephenC I agree. We shouldn't. That's why I didn't go beyond the contradiction in terms.

Comment: This should not be reopened, it is fundamentally unclear.

Comment: @StephenC I agree that's it's a generally unhelpful question, even if I (presumably) guessed correctly with my answer (as it was accepted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a `List` of a class with three fields (in real life, write getters, I've omitted them for simplicity):

```
class Record {
  public String string;
  public boolean bool;
  public Object object;
}
```

Then your code becomes:

```
List<Record> records = ...
for ( Record record: records) {
   if ( record.string.equals("type_of_element") && record.bool ) {
      // doing what I need with record.object
   }
}
```

This answer assumes that you might have many records which match. If you want to go directly to a single record which has a `string` element of `"type_of_element"` and a `bool` which is `true`, you could also use nested `Map`s:

```
Map<String,Map<Boolean,Object>> records = ...
Map<Boolean,Object> boolMap = records.get("type_of_element");
if (boolMap!= null) {
  Object obj = boolMap.get(true);
  if (obj != null) {
    // do your stuff on obj
  }
}
```

Comment: Wait, you voted to close the question, *and* you answered it?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  I voted to close before the OP added the code sample. Now I think it's answerable.

Comment: Wouldn't the most appropriate response then be to first retract your close-vote and then  post an answer? Currently, your answer stands, but no one else is able to post an answer, partly due to your vote.

Comment: I've voted to reopen, but I guess you're right -- my first action should have been to retract the close vote. (presumably the question must still have been open when I answered?)

Comment: @tgdavies , thank you a lot for your suggest , I am following that one with a little variation.... instead of `public Object object;` I am implementing as `private object_base object_type;` where `object_base` is a `class object_base<T> {...}` so I can store directly the object I am currently managing.... thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I think that your example is saying, you probably need just a `List<Object>` which you could use like this:

```
MyList List<Object> myList = ...

for (Object e: myList) {
    if (e instanceof Boolean) {
       Boolean b = (Boolean) e;
       // Use b ...
    }
    //  and so on
}
```

If you want to constrain the list to only containing (say) string or boolean values, you could do this:

```
public interface Element {
}

public class BooleanElement {
   private final boolean value;
   // constructors, getters, setters as required
}

public class StringElement;
   private final String value;
   // constructors, getters, setters as required
}

List<Element> myList = ...

for (Element e: myList) {
    if (e instanceof BooleanElement) {
       boolean b = (BooleanElement) e.getValue();
       // Use b ...
    }
    //  and so on
}
```

---

However, if you find yourself needing a *mixed* (or heterogeneous) list of various types, there is a good chance that you have made a mistake in your design.  IMO.